# Zend debugger - External or Local IP

Tags: zend-studio, zend-debugger

I have just installed the zend debugger on a remote site and am trying to connect to it via Zend Studio 8.

I am connecting to the dummy php file fine. However it just times out.

Should I be using my external IP address?
Or the internal one used for the machine on my home network?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the remote site is not in your local network it sees the external ip address
so you have to use that one.
if the machine is in you local home network you have to use the local address.

is this what you needed? if i am missing the point let me know.

Comment: thanks - that's great. Alas, I still can't solve why I can't connect to the debugger.  When I click 'Test Debugger in Studio. Studio says a timeout occurred --- looking at the remote proxy. HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2011 20:41:27 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: The http response code 200 OK says that the site loaded ok, maybe you are connecting to the wrong path? the address seems o be right

Comment: Thanks,pretty much running out of ideas here. Server logs state : [Zend Debugger] Cannot connect to host [My Ip Address]

Comment: are you in the same local network? because if you're not you'd have to setup port forwarding in your router